# fitBounds function does not show all markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm fairly new to the Maps API, and I'm trying to work with a map in Sencha Touch.

I have an array of markers plotted on the map successfully. But I want to zoom and center the map to fit all the markers as tightly as possible.

When I call the fitBounds function, I get a view of the map in which all my markers are in the top left corner of the screen and the zoom is far too wide - not what I want.

Any tips on how to get all my markers on the map view with the closest possible zoom? Thanks!

```
function setCenter()
{
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
        //  And increase the bounds to take this point
        bounds.extend (LatLngList[i]);
    }

    map.getMap().fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot, what will you have after the `fitBounds`?

Comment: did my answer helped? need any more help?

Comment: Thanks for your response - I tried your suggestion but the map still puts all the markers just out of sight in the top left corner.

Answer (score 3):

what I use (after the for loop):

```
map_center = bounds.getCenter();
map.setCenter(map_center);
map.panToBounds(bounds);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

hope it helps!